# How to remove padding in text line on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I faced with a problem related to `Text` element in Jetpack Compose. I wanted to place two separated `Text` elements under each other but I can't remove their inner paddings to make them look like not so separated.
As you can see on pic below `Text` with "02" has these paddings. Is there any way to crop them?

I tried to use `.offset()` and `.height()` modifiers to change the `Text` box size, but it looks like a really awful solution.

Code example to reproduce:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(65.dp)
        .width(65.dp)
        .background(Color.White)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "00",
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5.copy(
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
            ),
            color = Color.Black,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
        Text(
            text = "Text",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
            color = Color.Gray,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: this padding on the picture really looks huge, show us [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think you're looking for the font padding... Check this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171394808 I think it will be fixed on compose 1.2

Comment: @PylypDukhov I've added an example

Comment: Have the same problem, but this issue does not help issuetracker.google.com/issues/171394808 , it's something different. I also used offset and height , but the impl is a little bit ugly . I use Compose 1.2 beta 2, at this time .

Comment: it is so stupid that compose just can't remove font padding at all... the best solution for now described here https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b

Comment: @Demigod I find the article kind of empty, nothing interesting to solve the problem. I am stuck building this layout and can't turn off Text paddings.